# Deny IP to host name request?

Tags: linux, networking, hostname

My home computer is connected directly through a modem to my ISP. How can I prevent my IP to return a host name when I use this website ?

[IPtoHost](http://www.hcidata.info/host2ip.htm)

**EDIT:**

so... I take it that the request goes directly to my ISP and not to my computer ?

Comment: The request is going directly to your computer through your ISP.  Just like if I call your phone number, the call passes through your provider's (at&t) systems and your phone rings.  But in this case, your ISP is providing the "White Pages" listing for your number - the DNS entry.

Comment: @Matt, Umm no, the DNS request that the above website is doing never touches your computer (other than sending html output back to your computer).

Comment: @ErikA: Sorry - I was confusing his updated "request" with an actual IP request to his machine, not the DNS request to his provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have full control of the netblock you're in (which you don't), the only thing you can do is ask your ISP to remove the PTR record for your IP (which I doubt they'll agree to do).

Also, there's nothing special about that website. It's just a front-end to dig, host, nslookup, etc.

Regarding your edit, that's correct. The DNS request goes to the authoritative servers for your netblock, which in most cases, are run by your ISP.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  This is a DNS entry that is owned by your provider.  You could ask them to change it for you, but you probably won't get far - especially since your IP is probably changing every time you connect.

Comment: Sorry about that edit...intended to edit my own answer. :)

Comment: no worries.....   :)